# create a list of exponential decay with a predetermine half-life python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a list of exponential decay  of fix length with a predetermine half-life as efficiently as possible.

so assuming I want I half-life of  1 and a list length of 5 it would return :

```
[1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to overcomplicate things when a simple list comprehension will do

```
r = 0.5
a = 1.0
n = 5
l = [a*r**i for i in xrange(n)]
```

for a half life of 2, set

```
r = 0.5 ** 0.5
[1.0, 0.7071067811865476, 0.5000000000000001, 0.35355339059327384, 0.25000000000000006]
```

Comment: how can I adjust if I want a half-life of 2 ?

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, only using list comprehension

```
half_life = [0.5**i for i in range(5)]
```

**output** **=** `[1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625]`

Comment: What is the `1*` for?  Just `0.5**i` should work fine.

Comment: @Ludisposed No it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it using a generator function and `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

def halflife(n=1):
    while True:
       yield n
       n /= 2

print(list(islice(halflife(), None, 5)))
# [1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625]

print(list(islice(halflife(2), None, 5)))
# [2, 1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125]
```

Comment: I guess I overthought the problem, but I still don't see the justification for a DV

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

def decay(start, half_life, length):
    coef = math.exp(-math.log(2)/half_life)
    return list(map(lambda t: start * coef ** t, range(length) ))

decay(1, 1, 6)
# [1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125]

decay(10, 2, 5)
# [10.0,
# 7.0710678118654755,
# 5.000000000000001,
# 3.5355339059327386,
# 2.5000000000000004]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
start = 1
times = 5
half_life = [start*0.5**i for i in range(times)]
print (half_life)
```

prints:

```
[1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625]
```

or if you don't want to change the list you can use a tuple, even faster:

```
half_life = tuple(start*0.5**i for i in range(times))
```

prints:

```
(1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625)
```

Simple program to demonstrate:

```
def half_life(start,times):
    return tuple(start*0.5**i for i in range(times))

keep = set('0123456789')
s = input(' Enter start value >')
s = int(''.join(filter(keep.__contains__, s)))
t = input(' Enter number of half lives >')
t = int(''.join(filter(keep.__contains__, t)))

print (half_life(s,t))
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the following:

```
import math
half = 1.0
decay = math.log(2) / half
length = 5

list_d = [math.exp(-decay * i) for i in range(0, length)]
```

Is it what you were looking for?